# Is it possible to ensure valid JAX-WS client marshaling for invalid xml symbols for SOAP binding?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

I have java (1.6) client, built over JAX-WS, JAXB, SOAP binding, calling wcf (3.5) service (basicHttpBinding).

When I'm trying to call the server with soap-invalid character (for example, [image]  (backspace, ...)) - I am failed on both directions:

When I am sending such text, I am failed (for both - marshaling and unmarshaling)  with exception

> javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: 
>   There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://company.com/XXXParams. 
>  
>   The InnerException message was '**There was an error deserializing the object of type XXX.MyParams. 
>
>   The byte 0x08 is not valid at this location.** Line 1, position 1177.'.

Please see InnerException for more details.

> at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24] at 
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:119)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24] at
>   
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24] at
>   
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24] at
>   
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
>   ~[?:1.6.0_24]

Comment: I know it's not what you've asked, but wouldn't you be better fixing the input?

Comment: this means to fix all input from all dialogs, specified by user (hard but possible), as well as all output, received from server (very-very-hard, almost impossible).